# Как передать события с окна в WPF на первое окно, находящееся под ним?

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

Нужно создать окно для эффекта водяного знака на экране. Вывести его поверх других окон и задать прозрачность получилось, но все события клика мышки уходят в него. Как добиться полной прозрачности окна для системы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте IntPtr для вашего окна. Например, создайте статический класс для [DllImport](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
public static class DllImporter
{
    const int WS_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020;
    const int GWL_STYLE = (-20);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int newStyle);

    public static void SetWindowTransparent(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        var style = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, extendedStyle | WS_TRANSPARENT);
    }
}
```

И в code-behind вашего прозрачного окна перепишите событие [OnSourceInitialized](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.onsourceinitialized?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
    var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
    DllImporter.SetWindowTransparent(hwnd);
}
```

После этого ваше окно не будет перехватывать события.

**UPD:**

Для вашего окна необходимы атрибуты в XAML: `WindowStyle="None" Topmost="True" AllowsTransparency="True"`

Для проверки - полупрозрачное окно с

```
<Window.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.5" Color="Red"/>
</Window.Background>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]